# System.NullReferenceException despite available data

Tags: c#, json

Hello I have here a json. In my code below it is html. My Problem is that I become this error : An Exception error of type "System.NullReferenceException" has occurred. I have also debug the code "html" have the json data but in the next to lines the Content are null.

```
"{\"data\":[{\"q_id\":\"1\",\"q_text\":\"Ich read technical.\"},{\"q_id\":\"2\",\"q_text\":\"I have a good appetit.\"},{\"q_id\":\"3\",\"q_text\":\"I wake up early in the morning.\"}
```

That is my code

```
var g = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(html) as Dictionary<string, object>;
var h = g["data"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
lbfield.Content = h["q_text"].ToString();
```

Comment: this json does not appear to be valid there are plenty of online Json Validator and formatters online [JSON Formmater & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: Yes the debugger show this so but it is json. I have an ident code of another json that looks the same but works. Therfore I do not know what I done wrong.

Comment: The text you have shown appears to start out as JSON but is truncated. Also, `g["data"]` is an array, not a record, so `h["q_text"]` is not going to work. Please use a JSON parser like [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).